# How to view (preview) excel file after upload in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

When I upload excel file and convert it to url blob using URL.createObjectURL() and a button when onClick it will show my excel file. But instead of watching it download it.

here is my code:

```
const onUploadFile1 = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]

    setFile(file)
}

const onClickToView = () => {
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(file), '_blank', 'noreferrer')
}
```

(*)I have used libraries to convert like xlsx, react-excel-renderer...but it's not what I want because it breaks the layout of the file or when in excel there is an image it doesn't display.

Can someone help me, the end goal I want is to view the excel file after uploading.
[image]
Thanks.